# Why does my split string return the specified part after doing the fucntion twice?

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

I have a function which gets data from a form and sends it to a POST request which sends it to my MongoDB database. This is the code from the function that uploads the image to IPFS, gets the part of the URL returned that has the IPFS hash, puts it into a variable, and sends the form info with the hash, hash name, type, and file to the POST request.

```js
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const created = await client.add(file);
    const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${created.path}`;
    setUrlArr(prev => [...prev, url]);
    const ipfsHash = urlArr.toString().split("https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/");
    console.log(ipfsHash);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  const ipfsHash = urlArr.toString().split("https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/");
  console.log(ipfsHash)
  const photoName = nameInput?.current?.value
  console.log(photoName);


  axios.post('/api/backend/uploadHash', {
      name: photoName,
      type: "file",
      hash: ipfsHash[1], // [1] is added because without it it just returns [ '' ] on first click
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('res', res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error in request', err);
    });

};
```

It sends the information to the POST request, no issues there, but when the POST request logs in the console what the content of the POST request is, it takes two clicks of the upload button to send the hash as well. Here's a console.log output:

```json
// upload button first press
{ name: 'testhash11111', type: 'file' }
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: new ObjectId("IDHERE")
}

// upload button 2nd press
{
  name: 'testhash11111',
  type: 'file',
  hash: 'QmP6LZe6yktzwpGJC733bL92FwyNJsukRf3pYSZrfiP6wD'
}
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: new ObjectId("IDHERE")
}
```

My question is, why does the hash take two clicks to show, and is there any way to get it to only take one click to get the hash?

Comment: What is `urlArr`?

Comment: it's not totally clear what's going on, but I suspect you're getting confused over the fact that when you call `setUrlArr`, then `urlArr` when accessed synchronously afterwards, as in your code, is still going to hold the previous value. If you need that value in the code, just use the result of what you just set it to.

Comment: Why do you assign `ipfsHash` twice with the same expression? Where is the output of `console.log(ipfsHash)`?

Comment: Also note that the handler completes before the post does. There's a race condition with the handler and the user pressing the button

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks, I think I know what you're saying here but not sure. I tried using urlArr instead of ipfsHash[1] but that just makes `hash: ''`

Comment: @Barmar I assigned it twice because I thought that would make it work, but clearly not.

Comment: @danh ah, so that's why it's not returning the file hash? Is there any way for it to "wait" until X is done before it does the post?

Comment: I see no race conditions here, you just have to replace the places you're using `urlArr` - which still holds whatever it did before the `setUrlArr` call, with the new value, which it seems will be `[...urlArr, url]` (of course `url` is only in scope inside the top block but you can easily assign it to an outer variable).

Comment: @RobinZigmond - it might be a poor choice of phrasing on my part. I mean a race with the user on the second button click.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I don't think I understand fully, could you explain more about urlArr and how I would replace it? For context (maybe this'll help) urlArr is just   `const [urlArr, setUrlArr] = useState([]);`

Comment: @Quiint perhaps it will be easier to explain with a simpler example. If you have a state variable called `count`, and suppose its current value is 0, then when you call `setCount(1)` inside an event handler (say), the `count` variable will still be 0 in the rest of that function. If you need to refer to 1 specifically in the function, just reference it as 1, not as `count`! More realistically, your state isn't hardcoded, but referring to `count + 1` in these places should do the job you want (and you could always extract it to a local variable called `newCount` or something for readability).

Comment: @RobinZigmond oh that makes more sense, thank you! I did that and it worked when I used the direct variable  Can't believe I didn't think of that before, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand everything in the OP code, so the only change I've suggested relates to handling the button and handling the async post at the end...

```
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
  // GOOD IDEA TO DISABLE THE BUTTON HERE
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const created = await client.add(file);
    const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${created.path}`;

    // as other commenters noted, some of this is hard to understand
    // if setUrlArr is async, we're going to need more syntax here
    setUrlArr(prev => [...prev, url]);
    const ipfsHash = urlArr.toString().split("https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/");
    console.log(ipfsHash);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  const ipfsHash = urlArr.toString().split("https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/");
  console.log(ipfsHash)
  const photoName = nameInput?.current?.value
  console.log(photoName);

  // notice the new try{} and awaiting the post
  // no then's, because we're using the await style
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/backend/uploadHash', {
      name: photoName,
      type: "file",
      hash: ipfsHash[1], // [1] is added because without it it just returns [ '' ] on first click
    });
    console.log('res', res.data);
    })
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('error in request', err);
  } finally {
    // GOOD IDEA TO RE-ENABLE THE BUTTON HERE
  }
  
};
```